# Different output of sorting code in Java 6 and Java 8

Tags: sorting, java-8, comparator, java-6

I have a below code written for sorting my data .
Output of this code is different in Java 6 and Java 8. Also the sequence in which objects are compared is reverse and I think this is causing change in final output.
The sorting algorithm may not be correct but still can someone please explain  why this is working this way ?

Please check attached code and output in Java 6 and Java 8.

**Code**

```
package assignements;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class ComparableObject {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean hidden;
    private Integer order;


    ComparableObject() {
    }

    ComparableObject(String id, String name, boolean hidden, Integer columnOrder) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.hidden = hidden;
        this.order = columnOrder;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }

    public void setHidden(boolean hidden) {
        this.hidden = hidden;
    }

    public Integer getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Integer order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}

public class ComparatorPoc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ComparableObject> list = new ArrayList<ComparableObject>();
        list.add(new ComparableObject("1547", "id", false, 10));
        list.add(new ComparableObject("1548", "name", true, 20));
        list.add(new ComparableObject("1592", "customername", false, 30));
        list.add(new ComparableObject("1549", "customername", true, 40));
        list.add(new ComparableObject("1551", "OrderTo", false, 50));
        list.add(new ComparableObject("1553", "PO", true, 60));

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ComparableObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ComparableObject o1, ComparableObject o2) {
                System.out.println(o1.getName());
                System.out.println(o2.getName());
                System.out.println("****************");
                boolean o1Hidden = o1.isHidden();
                boolean o2Hidden = o2.isHidden();
                if (o1Hidden && o2Hidden)
                    return 0;
                else if (o1Hidden)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
        });

        for (ComparableObject p : list) {
            System.out.println("Id=" + p.getId() + " Name=" + p.getName() + " Column Order=" + p.getOrder() + " IsHidden=" + p.isHidden());
        }
    }
}
```

**Java 6 Output**

```
id
name
****************
name
customername
****************
id
customername
****************
name
customername
****************
customername
OrderTo
****************
name
OrderTo
****************
customername
OrderTo
****************
customername
PO
****************
Id=1547 Name=id Column Order=10 IsHidden=false
Id=1592 Name=customername Column Order=30 IsHidden=false
Id=1551 Name=OrderTo Column Order=50 IsHidden=false
Id=1548 Name=name Column Order=20 IsHidden=true
Id=1549 Name=customername Column Order=40 IsHidden=true
Id=1553 Name=PO Column Order=60 IsHidden=true
```

**Java 8 Output**

```
name
id
****************
customername
name
****************
customername
name
****************
customername
id
****************
customername
id
****************
customername
name
****************
OrderTo
name
****************
OrderTo
id
****************
OrderTo
customername
****************
PO
id
****************
PO
customername
****************
Id=1551 Name=OrderTo Column Order=50 IsHidden=false
Id=1592 Name=customername Column Order=30 IsHidden=false
Id=1547 Name=id Column Order=10 IsHidden=false
Id=1548 Name=name Column Order=20 IsHidden=true
Id=1549 Name=customername Column Order=40 IsHidden=true
Id=1553 Name=PO Column Order=60 IsHidden=true
```

Comment: Your comparator returns `-1` whenever both objects are not "hidden", so it doesn't correctly implement the comparator protocol. Therefore sorting behaviour is not deterministic.

Comment: You can fix your comparator by using `return (o1Hidden ^ o2Hidden) ? o1Hidden ? 1 : -1 : 0;`.  The difference is that it `returns 0` when `o1Hidden == o2Hidden`.   Since that case is resolved, you can proceed to test exclusively on `o1Hidden`, `returning 1 for true and -1 for false`.  Now whether that is what you intended (or meets your sort requirements) is up to you.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3 and WJS for your suggestions. I know that my sorting code has a bug and I know how to fix this . I just wanted to know why sequence of comparison changing in Java 6 and 8 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All guarantees given by methods using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) assume that the `Comparator` correctly implements [the `compare` contract](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)). But there are several easy ways in which it can be subtly broken.

In your specific case you break the constract that the signs of `compare(a, b)` and `compare(b, a)` have to be opposite (unless they both return `0`) when `hidden` is `false` for both `a` and `b`:

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.

Since you broke the contract, the exact behaviour of the `sort()` method is no longer specified.

There has probably been a change in the sorting algorithm used between Java 6 and Java 8, which means that they handle this (unspecified) situation differently. That's not a bug in the `sort` code.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why one should carefully read and obey the contracts specified in the API.   Otherwise,  serious repercussions could result in real world applications.

Comment: @WJS: `Comparator` and `equals`/`hashCode` are definitely the biggest stumbling blocks in the JDK wrt this.

Comment: …and that you can save a lot of hassle by letting the built-in tools do the job, i.e. `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(ComparableObject::isHidden));` does more than save typing. It eliminates error sources.